# Node Sass Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'

Tags: node.js, sass, yarnpkg

I have the following package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "*",
    "buble": "^0.12.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "gulp": "*",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-browsersync-official": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "sass": "*",
    "sass-loader": "*",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-stash": "^2.0.1-beta",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
    "jquery-simple-upload": "^1.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "moment": "*",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.24"
  }
```

On using Yarn to install the modules I am met with

> warning "laravel-elixir-vue-2 > sass-loader@4.1.1" has unmet peer
> dependency "webpack@^2 || ^2.2.0-rc.0 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^1.12.6".
> [4/4] Building fresh packages... error
> /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/node_modules/node-sass:
> Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: node scripts/install.js
> Arguments: Directory:
> /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/node_modules/node-sass
> Output: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp' Require stack:
>
> - /home/vagrant/modules/xxx/node-sass/scripts/install.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   at Object. (/home/vagrant/modules/xxx/node-sass/scripts/install.js:7:11)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
>   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: [
>   '/home/vagrant/modules/xxx/node-sass/scripts/install.js' ]

I'm not sure why/ who is installing node-sass but it brings me to this point regardless if I `yarn clean cache` `rm -rf package.lock.json` or `rm -rf node_modules`

I'm using

**yarn 1.22.10
node 12.20.0
npm 6.14.9**

on **Linux homestead 4.15.0-124-generic #127-Ubuntu**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like node LTS is 14.something.

Maybe try updating that (and everything else)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where install "mkdirp".

but you can install mkdirp@lastest first,

then let yarn/npm install all package again

to see whether "mkdirp" is a really problem or not.

```
yarn add mkdirp@lastest // or npm i mkdirp@lastest
```

then

```
yarn install // or npm i
```

Comment: Believe it or not....I tried that both globally and otherwise and then i would get `Cannot find module true-case-path`, Then `Cannot find module glob` and then `Cannot find module fs.realpath` and so forth and so forth. Seems a bit tedious.

Comment: Dont give up mate!. 
It seems just screwed up in dependencies.
let it install module by module individually.

I think we have no choice but to untie the knots one by one